# Save ASP.NET error without showing it to visitor

Tags: asp.net, error-handling

Many of you will have seen an error like the one below.
Now, I don't want to show it to the user in such a screen, but rather show a friendly message like "sorry, something went wrong". Now showing such a page is no problem at all. But I want to save the exact error message as is shown in the screen below in my database, so I can work on it later.

I want to do this without having to write try/catch statement all over the place in my website.
Is that possible?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

take a look at this :

```
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <customErrors defaultRedirect="GenericError.htm"
                  mode="RemoteOnly">
      <error statusCode="500"
             redirect="InternalError.htm"/>
    </customErrors>
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h0hfz6fc.aspx

Answer (score 1):

You can manage it in web.config. Please reference it.

[ASP.NET Customer Error](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h0hfz6fc.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Global.asax Application_Error event.

protected void Application_Error(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Exception ex = Server.GetLastError().GetBaseException();
            //Log the exception...
        }